# Unable to locate element in Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I try to login on my Wlan Repeater and restart it, it logs in and goes to the site where the "Reboot" Button is, sadly Selenium does not find the button.
That's the button:

```
<button type="submit" name="reboot">Neu starten</button>
```

but if I try this:

```
reboot = browser.find_element_by_name('reboot')
reboot.submit()
```

I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"reboot"}
```

Comment: What about `.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@name='reboot']")`?

Comment: Does not work also

Comment: Is it inside an `iframe`?

Comment: `//button[contains(text(),'Neu starten')]`

Comment: Does not work also and it isnt in a Iframe

Comment: Can you add more HTML code for this button?

Comment: I hope this is enough (?) I am not really comfortable with HTML: `<form action="/system/reboot.lua" method="POST">
<div id="btn_form_foot">
<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="84608b57896e6f39">
<button type="submit" name="reboot">Neu starten</button>
</div>
</form>`

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this exception.

- Element is in different frame
- You have landed on the wrong page (some kind of assertion would help)
- page has not loaded and you are trying to find the element (Explicit Wait methods will help in this case)
- identifier is wrong (which is not in your case)

Investigate these things and you will find out the solution.

Comment: Im on the right page and it is also loaded (i think?), i mean i could click on the button by myself because the site is open and loaded

Comment: @MushroomMauLa there could be the case of iframe as well, and try using explicit wait. I told you couple of possibilities, don't just stick to one.

Comment: It is not in a frame as much as i know, like I said above. If I try to add `time.sleep(5)` before `reboot = browser.find_element_by_name('reboot')
reboot.submit()` chrome closes and a windows pops up : chromedriver.exe does not work anymore. If I try it in Firefox the console just closes but it does not click the button.

Comment: time.sleep does not mean **explicit wait**. Google it to understand what I am saying. however, if putting sleep doesn't throw any error which means, if you have different issue and not the one you have mentioned in your question. it seems like two element has the same name. form an xpath and check in **firebug xpather plugin**

Comment: OK i tried Explicit wait, but if I add `wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'reboot)))'` the console just opens for a second and instantly closes and does not even open the browser neither Chrome nor Firefox. I also checked the xpath with firebug it only shows up the reboot button.

Comment: update the question with this details and the error you are getting after this.

Comment: as i said, update the question so that others can also understand it. and it seems like there are two elements with the same name. try different xpath. i.e. `//button[@type="submit"]`